# Dependency Errors in ASP.NET application C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

When I put in "AddJsonFile("foo.json") as a method on IconfigurationBuilder, it throws this error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS1061  'ConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddJsonFile' and no extension method 'AddJsonFile' accepting a first argument of type 'ConfigurationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WebDemo.DNX 4.5.1   E:\ASP.NET\WebDemo\src\WebApplication1\Startup.cs   21

After doing potential fixes and adding the DNX 4.5.1 package, I then get this error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS1061  'ConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddJsonFile' and no extension method 'AddJsonFile' accepting a first argument of type 'ConfigurationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WebDemo.DNX Core 5.0    E:\ASP.NET\WebDemo\src\WebApplication1\Startup.cs   21

If I delete the method, I get this error when I run the application:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.IConfigurationSource' from assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.RuntimeHttpApplication.ApplicationStart(IHttpApplication application)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.HttpApplicationBase.InvokeApplicationStart(IHttpApplication application)

Here is my Project.Json File:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "jQuery": "2.1.4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta8"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-beta8"
      }
    }
  },

  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

I am Also getting these Warnings!

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Warning     The element 'Target' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid child element 'GetBuildOptions' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'. List of possible elements expected: 'Task, AL, AspNetCompiler, AssignCulture, AssignProjectConfiguration, AssignTargetPath, AxImp, CallTarget, CombinePath, ConvertToAbsolutePath, Copy, CreateCSharpManifestResourceName, CreateItem, CreateProperty, CreateVisualBasicManifestResourceName, Csc, Delete, Error, Exec, FindAppConfigFile, FindInList, FindUnderPath, FormatUrl, FormatVersion, GenerateApplicationManifest, GenerateBootstrapper, GenerateDeploymentManifest, GenerateResource, GenerateTrustInfo, GetAssemblyIdentity, GetFrameworkPath, GetFrameworkSdkPath, GetReferenceAssemblyPaths, LC, MakeDir, Message, Move, MSBuild, ReadLinesFromFile, RegisterAssembly, RemoveDir, RemoveDuplicates, RequiresFramework35SP1Assembly, ResolveAssemblyReference, ResolveComReference, ResolveKeySource, ResolveManifestFiles, ResolveNativeReference, ResolveNonMSBuildProjectOutput, SGen, SignFile, TlbImp, Touch, UnregisterAssembly, UpdateManifest, Vbc, VCBuild, Warning, WriteCodeFragment, WriteLinesToFile, XslTransformation, CodeAnalysis, CL, Link, BSCMake, CPPClean, Get....   Miscellaneous Files C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets   140

Comment: Maybe this discussion will be helpful: [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/25).